# IDisposable with Multiple Levels of Inheritance

Tags: c#, .net, oop, idisposable

Suppose you have the following inheritance chain:

```
class A : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()...
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)...
}

class B : A
{
    // Virtual or Override for B?
}

class C : B
{
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)...
}
```

If A, B, and C each have their own private IDisposable resources, how should B declare `Dispose(bool)`?

Comment: Is it possible to declare two void Dispose with no params in a single class?

Comment: You just call `base.Dispose()` and free own for `B` resources. What is the problem?

Comment: The pattern actually calls for `protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)` so your question is borked before you started.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should **override**, not **hide**:

```
class A : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose() {
      Dispose(true);
      GC.SuppressFinalize(this); // <- May be excluded
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(Boolean disposing)... // <- "disposing" recommended by Microsoft
}

class B : A
{
    protected override void Dispose(Boolean disposing) {
      // Dispose here all private resources of B
      ...
      base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}

class C : B
{
    protected override void Dispose(Boolean disposing) {
      // Dispose here all private resources of C
      ...
      base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Comment: Marking this one as answer because you address the override part, and the fact that `base.Dispose()` should be called. I feel like a dummy for asking this question now, i knew that!

Comment: Would you recommend to add a destructor within each of these classes (and calling this.Dispose(false);)? What if class A and B were abstract classes, would your solution be any different?

Comment: @progLearner: c# doen't have *destructor*, but *finalizer*; when you implement finalizer, please, note that order in which finalizeres are executed is *no specified* so you should not use *reference* type fields. So, probably, the only relevant case for `~C()` is when you acquire the resource as low level structure (pointer `IntPtr`). It doesn't matter if `A` or `B` or both of them are `abstract` classes or not

Comment: Thanks. I am asking about the finaliser, because I want to make sure Dispose() is called by my client application when shut down. Is that not what the finalizer is supposed to be for?

Comment: @progLearner: when *application* (i.e. *process*) shuts down, OS will release all the resources acquired - opened files, streams etc.; if you want to ensure that some *special* resources (like rdbms connections) are properly released (say, commited and closed) you can try use `Application.ApplicationExit` event and the like. Please, note, that *finalizer* can well be *not* executed at all

Answer (score 3):

It should declare it using `override`. If it declares using `virtual` instead of `override`, then that would *hide* the `A.Dispose`.

By the way, you cannot declare two `Dispose` methods within `A`, both with no parameters (they cannot differentiate by return type or by accessors).

Comment: Thanks, that was a typo on my part